# Method does not exist or incorrect signature: [List<X_Opportunity__c>].addError(String)

Tags: apex

I am getting the below error in this method. Can anyone let me know what is wrong in this methd -

> Method does not exist or incorrect signature:
>   [List].addError(String)

```
 public static void opportunityUp(List<X_Opportunity__c> o)
    {
        List<X_Opportunity_Sales_Team__c> salesTeams = getOpportunitySalesTeams(o);

        List<Id> groups = getOpportunityGroups(o, salesTeams);

        List<User> inactiveUsers = getInactiveUsers(salesTeams);
        if (inactiveUsers.size() > 0 )
        {
            String errorMsg = 'Error Found : ';
            for (User user : inactiveUsers)
            {
                errorMsg = errorMsg + user.Name + ' ';
            }
            o.addError(errorMsg); 
            return;
    }
```

Regards

Comment: `o` is type of `List<X_Opportunity__c>`, but `addError` should be used on type of `sObject`

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it appears to be abandoned.

Answer (score 0):

Just replace the line with `o[0].addError(errorMsg);`

addError is a method of sObject class

Comment: How can you confirm that issue is exactly with the first element?

Comment: I can't however his code doesn't seem to report the error on the exact record, so just to throw an error, he can take the first element.

Answer (score -1):

The issue is that `addError` is a method on the `sObject` class (see the [official docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_sobject.htm#apex_System_SObject_addError)), but you're trying to use it on `o` - a `List` of `sObjects`.

You can call `X_Opportunity__c.addError(errorMsg);` to add an error to an individual `X_Opportunity__c`.